# How to preemptively block a non-contact on whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, privacy

[I read this QA](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83299/how-to-restrict-stranger-messages-in-whatsapp) but it didn't specfically address my question. I also only found how to block a contact or someone that already sent you a message.

Say I have blocked numbers on my phone. They are not contacts. I don't want to hear from them. I don't want them to message me - ever.

How can I block someone when there's no chat between myself and them? (avoid potential harassment)

Or, alternatively, can I make it to only receive messages from people on *my* list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

On Whatsapp you can't block people just by their usernames. You must open the chat between you two and block the person from the right-top menu. However, you can add that number as a contact, open the Whatsapp chat screen (you don't have to chat them. Just open their chat screen.) block them and then delete them from your contacts again.

And **no** again.

Whatsapp doesn't support a feature like *"Receive texts from my contacts only."* But you can reduce what people who aren't in your contacts can see about your profile (Last seen, Profile photo, Status)

Comment: That's the conclusion I pretty much reached, but I was hoping differently. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am worrying over a similar concern (stalker at work) and what I have done is this: I save his number on my phone. Then I open WhatsApp and go to Settings > Account > Privacy > Blocked Contacts > and then I add this person, who appears on my WhatsApp list, to the blocked list.

I use a different number for my professional network and another number for family & friends (also WhatsApp, WeChat, etc.) and so far haven't received any WhatsApp text from this creepy coworker. However recently my private mobile number was accidentally leaked to him, so if I do hear from him on WhatsApp I will update this entry.

Also, I set my WhatsApp settings so that only my contacts can see my status and my photo. To do the same, go to Settings > Account > Privacy > Who Can See My Personal Info > change your preferences there. You can also set it so that nobody can see your status and photo.

Hope this helps.